# ASP.NET - How To View MS Word File from server, edit then save on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed an (C#) asp.net web application based on document management
and I want to view the selected ms word file from server files on the client machine then when the client save the selected file, It will be saved back on server.

Answer (score 2):

The trick to this is Share Point. It allows you to checkout and check-in documents straight from MS Word. So essentially, your ASP.NET application will be a cataloging tool that lists urls for users.

Without share point, the solution is very brittle and not worth implementing. You, essentially, have to download the file and open it word. This can be easily achieved by returning the document in your response. The difficult part is to send it back.

Another option is you have the word document in a shared drive instead of the webserver. I am betting that this is what you want anyway. The problem you will have is that you can't control permission from your web app, but through active directory.

Answer (score 0):

if a third-part component works for you, aceoffix can be one of your alternative. You can code for the users and allow them to login to access some specified document. Users can view, edit the document and save it back to the server too.

Answer (score -1):

well i think the best way to go is using [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

You can create, modify, save... and whatever you like with a MSWord document.
Check [here](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/creating-word-document-using-c/) for some examples... i am sure you can manage to find other examples.

Basically you should open the MSWord file to your client as an item of that class and after he is done editing... save it again on your server...